# Two charts to cover a circle (as a smooth manifold)

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm aware there are a couple of questions tackling this. It's just that I thought of a solution to this and just wanted to verify it. Hope this kind of question is okay.

So the problem is to cover a circle using just 2 coordinate patches. So I can consider two charts $(U,x)$ (whole circle with top point removed) and $(V,y)$ (whole circle with bottom point removed). Such that $x(p)=\theta$, where $\theta$ the angle traced out like so:
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/courses-images/wp-content/uploads/sites/3675/2018/09/27003528/CNX_Precalc_Figure_05_02_0022.jpg

And $y(p)=\pi+\theta$. From what I see, the transition maps are smooth (they just differ by a constant). And the charts cover the circle.

But I'm not 100% sure about this - any errors, or anything that I'm missing?

Comment: Try writing out full details. I don’t see how the north and south pole are relevant.

Comment: The idea is right, but you should be clearer about what happens to $x$ and $y$ when you cross the removed points. Each chart needs to be continuous on its domain.

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at the articles [Inscribed angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle), then [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) on Wikipedia. For the latter, the definition using the tangent half-angle formula.

Comment: @Karl: I thought about your comment. So I guess the issue would be that the image of $x$ would be $[0,\pi/2) \cup (\pi/2,2\pi]$ - and this isn't an open set in $\mathbb{R}$. I need to think a bit more about an appropriate selection of chart maps

Comment: @TedShifrin: Okay here's what I'm thinking: $U$ can be the whole circle with the rightmost point removed. $x(p)=\theta$ so this time the image of $x$ would be $(0,2\pi)$. $V$ can be the right half of the circle (excluding north and south poles) with $y(p)=\sin\theta$, and now the image of $y$ is $(-1,1)$. Is this okay?

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all... Note that the map
$$
(x, y) \mapsto \operatorname{sgn(y)}\arccos(x)
$$
is a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{S}^1\setminus\{(0, -1)\}$ and $]-\pi, \pi[$.

**Hint:** To get a homeomorphism between $]-\pi, \pi[$ and $\mathbb{S}^1$ minus one point simply [rotate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) the plane by a angle $\varphi$, i.e., use the map
$$
(x, y)\mapsto \operatorname{sgn(\sin(\varphi) x + \cos(\varphi)y)}\arccos(\cos(\varphi) x - \sin(\varphi)y).
$$

You charts need to use $\varphi$ equals $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$, respectively.